# kubernetes get host dns name to container for kafka advertise host

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, kubernetes

I want to deploy kafka on kubernetes.

Because I will be streaming with high bandwidth from the internet to kafka I want to use the hostport and advertise the hosts "dnsName:hostPort" to zookeeper so that all traffic goes directly to the kafka broker (as opposed to using nodeport and a loadbalancer where traffic hits some random node which redirects it creating unnecessary traffic).

I have setup my kubernetes cluster on amazon. With `kubectl describe node ${nodeId}` I get the internalIp, externalIp, internal and external Dns name of the node.

I want to pass the externalDns name to the kafka broker so that it can use it as advertise host.

How can I pass that information to the container? Ideally I could do this from the deployment yaml but I'm also open to other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I pass that information to the container? Ideally I could do this from the deployment yaml but I'm also open to other solutions.

The first thing I would try is `envFrom: fieldRef:` and see if it will let you reach into the `PodSpec`'s `status:` field to grab the `nodeName`. I deeply appreciate that isn't the `ExternalDnsName` you asked about, but if `fieldRef` works, it could be a lot less typing and thus could be a good tradeoff.

But, with "I'm also open to other solutions" in mind: don't forget that -- unless instructed otherwise -- each Pod is able to interact with the kubernetes API, and with the correct RBAC permissions it can request the very information you're seeking. You can do that either as a `command:` override, to do setup work before launching the kafka broker, or you can do that work in an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/), write the external address into a shared bit of filesystem (with `volume: emptyDir: {}` or similar), and then any glue code for slurping that value into your kafka broker.

I am 100% certain that the `envFrom: fieldRef:` construct that I mentioned earlier can acquire the `metadata.name` and `metadata.namespace` of the Pod, at which point the Pod can ask the kubernetes API for its own `PodSpec`, extract the `nodeName` from the aforementioned `status:` field, then ask the kubernetes API for the Node info, and voilà, you have all the information kubernetes knows about that Node.

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work. I used the python kubernetes client, a sidecar container as you said and a shared volume. A Serviceaccount (default namespace), ClusterRole and clusterRolebinding to give the necessary permissions. Took me a day but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Matthew L Daniels answer describes the valid approach of querying the kubernetes api using the nodename which is obtained by an env var. The difficulty lies in giving the pod the proper rbac access and setting up an init Container.

Here the kubernetes yml that implements this with an init container using the python kubernetes client:

```
### This serviceAccount gives the kafka sidecar the permission to query the kubernetes API for node information so that it can find out the advertise host (node public dns name) for the kafka which uses hostPort to be as efficient as possible.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: node-reader-service-account
  namespace: default
---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: node-reader-cluster-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""] # The API group "" indicates the core API Group.
    resources: ["nodes"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-nodes-rolebinding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount # May be "User", "Group" or "ServiceAccount"
    name: node-reader-service-account
    namespace: default 
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: node-reader-cluster-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: kafka
  name: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: kafka
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: node-reader-service-account
      containers:

      - name: kafka
        image: someImage
        resources: {}
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=$(cat '/etc/sidecar-data/dnsName') && env | grep KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS && /start-kafka.sh"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: sidecar-data
          mountPath: /etc/sidecar-data/

      initContainers:
      - name: kafka-sidecar
        image: sidecarImage
        command: ["python"]
        args: ["/script/getHostDnsName.py", "$(KUBE_NODE_NAME)", "/etc/sidecar-data/dnsName"]
        env:
          - name: KUBE_NODE_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        volumeMounts:
        - name: sidecar-data
          mountPath: /etc/sidecar-data/

      volumes:
      - name: sidecar-data
        emptyDir: {}

      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```